# Getting all info from a Flex object/module

Tags: apache-flex

I'm wondering if there's any reasonable way to get a reference to an object in Flex, and look through everything in every sub object (every property and everything).  That is, I want to know if I can completely map all of the data within an object, from another object.  I'm aware that this wouldn't work for private (or protected) members, but for anything public, it should be possible, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [describeType](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) for class instances, and

```
 for (var str:String in obj) { trace (str+":"+obj[str]); }
```

for simple Objects.

Comment: "simple"?  The objects in question will have both visual and non-visual elements, they may also have objects within objects within objects etc...

Comment: By simple objects, I mean "Object" objects without a class hierarchy: `var obj:Object = {x:13, y:14};`.  You can use describeType to get the class variables and accessors, then trace the content. Each member type can also be described, and so on.  You could implement a recursive function parsing all visible values, until there are only simple data type members.

Comment: That's what I figured - but I was hoping there was some built in thing that could handle it.  I might have to do this (although this way, in the context of what I'm doing, will require writing parsing "x is Label" etc for every component in Flex, if I understand what you're saying).

Comment: Do it like this: Create a helper class with a static method using `describeType( obj )..accessor`, resp. `describeType( obj )..variable`, to get XMLLists.  Then for each xml in the list, call `obj[xml.@name]` to get the member value, then call the same helper method on the returned value, etc.  You can store the XML result from describeType for each class in a static array, so you can do a simple lookup if the class has already been described once.

Comment: Hmm, smart - I'll look into this.